# Proper sorting of dataset in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, dataset

In the table1, I have a column: cCLLID,cCLID,nLID
my problem is sorting the numeric field nLID.
ex. the records of nLID are: 1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12
when i use the code below, the records of nLID are: 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5

```
 For Each row As DataRow In .sDataSet.Tables("Table1").Select("cCLID='" & _cCLID.Text_Value & "'", "cCLID,nLID") 
   row("nLID") = j
   row("cCLLID") = row("cCLID") & "-" & row("nLID")
   j = j + 1
 Next
```

Comment: You're not showing any sorting code, but I hope it's obvious that the sort is being done on a string representation rather than treating the values as numeric. But you've not shown us any relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do:

**EDIT**

```
DataView dv = sDataSet.Tables("Table1").DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "nLID";
```

Now, just use Dataview `dv`

Comment: what about my condtions? "cCLID='" & _cCLID.Text_Value & "'"

Comment: I have edited my answer..have you noticed..?? Where You will see the sorted view in `dv` which you can use further in the for each loop...@dave

Comment: yes i see it..but dataview cannot pass to datarow...how is that?